# Why does setting the pivot to right most element in a QuickSort implementation not work?

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

My current implementation of QuickSort with setting the pivot to the last element in the array is causing a stack overflow exception. Setting it to the middle element, or left most, works fine but not the right. I am really trying to understand why.

I am currently learning data structures and algorithms and am really trying to understand the intricacies of how algorithms work. I've tried stepping through the below problem but recursion is killing me.

Basically I set my pivot to last element in the array and find all less than the pivot and increment left to become the wall. All elements greater are swapped to the right.

Here is my solution

```
 public static void QuickSort_Recursive(int[] array, int left, int right)
    {

        // only proceed if left is less than right
        if(left < right)
        {
            // get index for left and right barrier
            int pivotIndex = Partition(array, left, right);

            // sort left
            QuickSort_Recursive(array, left, pivotIndex - 1);

            // sort right
            QuickSort_Recursive(array, pivotIndex, right);
        }
    }

    public static int Partition(int[] array, int left, int right)
    {
        // get pivot as last element            
       int pivot = array[right];

        // continue until left passes right
        while (left <= right)
        {
            // continue with left side until you find an element greater than pivot
            while(array[left] < pivot)
            {
                left++;
            }

            // Continue with right until you find an element less than the pivot
            while(array[right] > pivot)
            {
                right--;
            }

            // Only swap if left is less than right
            if(left <= right)
            {
                // swap left and right
                Swap(array, left, right);

                // Increment left and decrement right
                left++;
                right--;
            }

        }

        return left;
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand why setting it to the right most element causes a stack overflow exception?

**EDIT:** Below is an implementation that does work with the pivot being the most right but they key to this one is 1) it doesn't include the pivot in swapping until the very end 2) only moves the left pointer so you keep track of where the barrier between low and high is 3) does not move both pointers

```
        // Make starting pivot the last one for now
        int pivot = array[right];
        int leftWall = left;

        // Go through array until index before pivot is reached
        for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
        {
            // If item at array[i] is less than or equal to pivot then switch with leftwall
            if(array[i] <= pivot)
            {
                // Swap positions with leftWall
                Swap_Memory(array, i, leftWall);

                // Increment leftwall position
                leftWall += 1;
            }
        }

        // Swap pivot with whatever value is the top lowest number (pivot is 'right' in this case)
        Swap_Memory(array, leftWall, right);

        // return leftwall as pivot
        // Leftwall is barrier between values lower than pivot and those higher
        return leftWall;
```

Comment: -->> QuickSort_Recursive(array, pivotIndex + 1, right);

Comment: nope, that did not fix it.

Comment: it may not have done, but it was incorrect!

Comment: Provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem if you want Stack Overflow users to help debug. In the meantime, try using the debugger yourself. Step through the code, watch the variables, and when one of the variables isn't holding the value you expected or the code takes a path you didn't expect, you found your bug.

Comment: What happens when left has an item and right is null?  Do you have a tree that is left justified or a tree where left is null and right contains data?

Comment: Just an array. Here is a sample input: [2, 3, 11, 11, 6, 7, 7, 0, 1, 4]

Comment: re: why `pivot = array[right]` causes exception -- `while (left <= right) { while (array[left] < pivot) ++left; ... } return left;` _might_ cause `left > right`  You ultimately return `left` which is NOT a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your partition implementation.
You have to partition in such way that all elements to the left of index of pivot should be less than pivot element.
Following 2 things has to be addressed in code:

- All the comparisons, should be based pivot and not on indexes.
- Also, return value should be the index of selected pivot element.

Standard quicksort partitioning looks something like below:

```
    public static void QuickSort_Recursive(int[] array, int left, int right)
    {

        // only proceed if left is less than right
        if(left < right)
        {
            // get index for left and right barrier
            int pivotIndex = Partition(array, left, right);

            // sort left
            QuickSort_Recursive(array, left, pivotIndex-1);

            // sort right
            QuickSort_Recursive(array, pivotIndex+1, right);
        }
    }

    public static int Partition(int[] array, int left, int right)
    {
      // get pivot as last element            
      int pivot = array[right];

      int i = left - 1;

      for (int j = left; j <= right - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            // Make sure all the elements left of pivot index is less
            swap(array[i], array[j]);
        }
      }

      //Move the pivot to the selected index and return its index
      swap(array[i+1], pivot);

      return i + 1;

    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had used a different implementation, similar to yours, that solved the issue but it wasn't moving both left and right and swapping them. With the above implementation I can not get it to work with array[right[ as the pivot.I'll edit my post with an implementation that does so.

Comment: Your new implementation works for me with array[right] as pivot for few test cases. If you are facing some problem, can you post the test case array to be be sorted.

Comment: Right, the new implementation works but I am trying to get the original implementation to work with array[right] as the pivot. Really trying to understand why it isn't working